# Can anyone help me understand what's broken in the code below?

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

```
degree = {'name1': 'sam',
          'cert1': 'bachelors',
          'name2': 'Ann',
          'cert2': 'masters',
          'name3':'john',
          'cert3': 'associates',
          'name4': 'oz',
          'cert4': 'phd'
          }

print(degree)


def sch_degree(name, d_cert):
    for cert in degree:
        if cert == 'bachelors':
            return (f"{name1} is a four year holder of a {cert1}")
        else:
            if cert == 'associates':
                return (f"{name2} is a two year holder of a {cert2}")
            else:
                if cert == 'masters':
                    return (f"{name3} is a two year holder of a {cert3}")
                else:
                    if cert == 'phd':
                        return (f"{name4} is a four year holder of a {cert4}")


sch_degree(name1, cert1)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-238-4c32ecccc897>", line 1, in <module>
    sch_degree(name1, cert1)

NameError: name 'cert1' is not defined
```

Comment: well, what part of the error is not clear? `cert1` is being accessed before it is defined. Did you mean `degree['cert1']`?

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `sch_degree(degree['name1'], degree['cert1'])`? If so you will have other error also.

Comment: @DeepSpace the main objective is to print out the first sentence that reads: '{Sam} is a four year holder of a {bachelors}'. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your function by introducing a new dictionary:

```
degree = {'name1': 'sam',
          'cert1': 'bachelors',
          'name2': 'Ann',
          'cert2': 'masters',
          'name3': 'john',
          'cert3': 'associates',
          'name4': 'oz',
          'cert4': 'phd'
          }

cert_yr = {'bachelors': 'four',
           'masters': 'two',
           'associates': 'two',
           'phd': 'four'
           }


def sch_degree(n, c):
    return f"{degree[n]} is a {cert_yr[degree[c]]} year holder of a {degree[c]}"


print(sch_degree('name1', 'cert1'))
print(sch_degree('name2', 'cert2'))
print(sch_degree('name3', 'cert3'))
print(sch_degree('name4', 'cert4'))
```

Returning:

```
sam is a four year holder of a bachelors
Ann is a two year holder of a masters
john is a two year holder of a associates
oz is a four year holder of a phd
```

Comment: Thank you, brotha! I've got a long way to go.